Is there a way to find a scammer who stole my Bitcoin from coinbase wallet
Scammer has stolen my Bitcoin from coinbase wallet. If anyone can help me trace the scammer and recover my Bitcoin, will reward them with 10,000 dollars . Details below
Bitcoin Transaction Hash:
71542d230f205c49af276343390995c59b74020ab4a7d9cb063c1f47c4725a9a
Scammer wallet
bc1q79lvela5ewhwyytye0rqqzeg47x02qlgkdz2x4

Address bc1q79lvela5ewhwyytye0rqqzeg47x02qlgkdz2x4
The address you referenced has received and then sent onward multiple very similar amounts in the week since the theft. I don't know what this pattern means but it seems inconsistent with the work of an opportunistic thief randomly hacking into wallets.
There is no simple way to find if that address belongs to an exchange or to a normal wallet. Even if you identified an exchange, the exchange is required by law in many countries to protect the personally identifying data of its customers. You would probably need the support of lawyers and police in the country the exchange is operating from. You would probably need good evidence to support your version of events.

Recovery
You should report theft to police but your chances of recovery must be near zero.
It is possible the address belongs to a slave in a fraud factory or someone pennyless and gullible who has been duped by a recruitment scam into becoming an unwitting or unwilling money launderer and in the intervening week the money has been washed through multiple cryptocurrencies and multiple exchanges and multiple mixers.

How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?


Recovery Fraud
You will be contacted by a large number of people recommending or  claiming to be bitcoin recovery specialists. All or almost all will be confidence tricksters. Never pay an advance fee to receive recovered money.

https://www.cftc.gov/LearnAndProtect/AdvisoriesAndArticles/RecoveryFrauds.htm
https://www.aura.com/learn/refund-and-recovery-scams


Thanks. I will not pay anything in advance. Is there a way to find out exchange the address belongs to

There is no simple way to find if that address belongs to an exchange or to a normal wallet. Even if you identified an exchange, the exchange is required by law in many countries to protect the personally identifying data of its customers. You would probably need the support of lawyers and police in the country the exchange is operating from. You would probably need good evidence to support your version of events.

Thanks. I noticed the link that scammer used to scam me has IP 172.66.47.46 which is registered for ISP Cloudflarenet. Will it be possible for FBI to find the location of the scammer from this IP ?

I know nothing about the capabilities of the FBI. You could find out by reporting your experience to them

I recently was scammed as well through bitcoin using Cash app. Once you realize what’s happening… It’s too late ..It just makes you sick, doesn’t it?
Anyway, I have screenshots of all the transactions.  I have the server names that were used.  Email names, network names and YouTube channels. We might need to share our screenshots with each other get our money back!!!!
